# Old Developer removed from Facebook Messenger admin role, now facebook is returning "fbErrorSubcode":492

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

The old developer on my facebook chatbot stopped working on the project and was removed from the 'Admin' role by another Admin.

Now, facebook returns:
  `{"statusCode":400,"id":"1234567","fbCode":190,"fbErrorSubcode":492,"fbMessage":"The user must be an administrator, editor, or moderator of the page in order to impersonate it. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication."}`

instead of replying to a user.

How do I resolve this?

Edit to add:I think this is mostly related to the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN variable. How do I change the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN that facebook creates for API use? The old(current) PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN is linked to his account.

[image: The Value Where 'You must select a Page...' appears is incorrect]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens describes how you generate page access tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to also remove the admin from the app admin role. This allowed the creation of a new PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN that never expires.

Answer (score 0):

The old dev must have been using his personal credentials for the chatbot, so when he was removed from the page as an admin, the service stopped letting his credentials access it for chatting.

You'll need to get the app updated with different credentials.

Comment: Hmmm I think this is mostly related to the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN variable. How do I change the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN that the app selects for API use?

Comment: This would be a good question to ask the person who developed the app. Without knowing the application, no one else would know where and how the variables are set for your particular application.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see I was confusing. I can change the env var PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN. However, this value is linked back to his account, so when the bot tries to use this access token, access is denied by facebook. I don't see how to change the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN generated by facebook.